# I keep getting the AttributeError: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'fetch_member' error

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to make a global XP Leaderboard on a multi-server bot.

If I only had `entry[0]` it would just post their ID into the embed.

pls help tyty in advanced <3

```py
class Menu(ListPageSource):
    def __init__(self, ctx, data):
        self.ctx = ctx

        super().__init__(data, per_page=10)

    async def write_page(self, menu, offset, fields=[]):
        offset = (menu.current_page*self.per_page) + 1
        len_data = len(self.entries)

        embed = Embed(title="XP Leaderboard", description="See who is on top!", colour=self.ctx.author.colour)
        embed.set_thumbnail(url=self.ctx.guild.me.avatar_url)
        embed.set_footer(text=f"{offset:,} - {min(len_data, offset+self.per_page-1):,} of {len_data:,} members.")
        
        for name, value in fields:
            embed.add_field(name=name, value=value, inline=False)

        return embed

    async def format_page(self, menu, entries):
        offset = (menu.current_page*self.per_page) + 1
        fields = []
        table = ("\n".join(f"{idx+offset}. {self.ctx.bot.fetch_member(entry[0]).display_name} (XP: {entry[1]} | Level {entry[2]})" 
                for idx, entry in enumerate(entries)))

        fields.append(("Ranks", table))

        return await self.write_page(menu, offset, fields)
```

UPDATE:
Updated my table string and now it comes with this error, still don't know how to fix anything.

````py
        table = ("\n" +  f"{idx+offset}. {await self.ctx.bot.fetch_user(entry[0]).display_name} (XP: {entry[1]} | Level {entry[2]}" 
                 for idx, entry in enumerate(entries))```
```py
<async_generator object Menu.format_page.<locals>.<genexpr> at 0x04A49A90>
````

(^ that sends in the embed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by passing in "from lib.bot import bot" where my imports are, then having this

```py
        table = ("\n".join(f"{idx+offset}. {bot.get_user(entry[0]).name} (XP: {entry[1]} | Level: {entry[2]})"
                   for idx, entry in enumerate(entries)))
```

Answer (score 0):

What you did is a generator. You want a list comprehension:

`table = [x.do_stuff() for x in some_iterable]`

This is a generator:

`a = (x.do_stuff() for x in some_iterable)`

Comment: i did that and i got a new error.
https://pastebin.com/ZAM8ccQv

Comment: Use `self.ctx.guild` instead of `self.ctx.bot.guild`

Comment: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'display_name' :/ @kr8gz

Comment: What are you passing into `entries`? `get_member` only accepts user IDs

Comment: entries in my DB are user IDs, the problem I have is that I want to have display names instead of their ID. @kr8gz

Comment: The function returns `None` if the member cannot be found ([docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.get_member))

Answer (score 0):

`fetch_member` is a [Guild](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=guild#discord.Guild) object method, you can retrieve one using [bot.get_guild](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=get_guild#discord.Client.get_guild)